# Responsive menu doesn't work - Joomla

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, jquery

I have a little problem. I have installed a responsive menu ([Sidr](http://www.berriart.com/sidr/)) on my Joomla Web site, but I have a little problem.

The problem is that the menu only work's on the home page and inside it stops... I'm geting an error.

Please help me solve this issue! I will be gratefull!

Here's my site: [Turdi](http://www.turdidesigns.com)

UPDATE:
Ok, now I've solved the problems in main pages, but still, the problem exist's in WEB Pages page... And it exist's because of the Contact form, when I disable it, it works. But still disabling the contact form is not an option, because I have more pages (witch are hidden at the moment) and there is the same problem. How Can I modify the script to be sure that it will work on all my pages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix it using this jquery noconflict method.

Documentation: [Here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/)

Comment: If you want more answers to your questions, you need to work on the way you post them. Try isolating your problem first, preferably with a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/). Half the time you will realize what the problem is just by doing that, and it's way easier for others to help you. People here want to help, but don't just throw your live/dev site on here and say "I get some error" (not even stating what error you get and where) and expect everybody to start debugging your code.

Comment: Thanks Alex, Next time I will do that!